# Não consigo instalar o Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, bootstrap-3, sass

Estou tentando instalar o node js. Porém ao término da instalação quando executo pelo cmd. node -- version é apresentado o erro abaixo.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você colocou o version separado do --, ambos devem ficar juntos. `node --version`

Answer (score 3):

Amigo vc está escrevendo errado....! não tem o espaço entre o `--` e o `version`.... deve ser assim `node --version` como o -- colado no version

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]